# Kinect SDK Hand Enter Listener Called Multiple Times

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am working on a WPF application with the Kinect and I have subclassed the KinectTileButton to create my own version with a timed click.

However, I have been using the Hand Enter listener and found that it is being called multiple times when the hand is hovering (showing steady) in the bounds of the button.

I have modified the smoothing of the kinect to the following values:

```
args.NewSensor.SkeletonStream.Enable(new TransformSmoothParameters() {
                    Smoothing = 0.95f,
                    Correction = 0.0f,
                    Prediction = 0.0f,
                    JitterRadius = 0.01f,
                    MaxDeviationRadius = 0.08f
                });
```

But I cannot imagine that would have an impact (unless the jitteriness is now now being shown on screen but the readings in the background mean that the hand is all over the place).

I welcome any thoughts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While some part of me feels that I should delete this question based on the triviality of the answer I have found, I will keep it up for reference in my documentation and should anyone else come across such a problem. 
My issue was simply the ordering of controls in a XAML file. The kinect region should be WITHIN the overarching layout manager (i.e. canvas, uniform grid, etc).